# Grails: Expose LoginController for programmatic login

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, groovy

So I am working on a Grails/Flex toy project.  I have a controller(LoginController) that I am using to perform backend authentication on my Flex app.  However, I have been unable to "find" my controller.  What I mean by that is I get a HTTP Status 404 error when trying to access

```
http://localhost:8080/OrlandoGrails/LoginController/login.json
```

Here is my sad, sad little controller as it is in its proof-of-concept state.

```
package orlandograils
class LoginController {

    static allowedMethods = [login: "POST", login: "GET"]

    def login(String username, String password )
    {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

I've seen the documentation concerning RESTful services, but they always seem to concern a domain object which I don't have.  In any case, I have also added this to my UrlMappings.groovy file

```
"/LoginController/login.json"(resource:"LoginController")
```

Any help on what I'm doing horribly wrong would be greatly appreciated. Also, is there a way to list Grails routes like one can with RoR or Symfony2?

Also, while the bulk of my services will be over the amf channels, my authentication is occurring over http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish but one problem with your sample is that in your URL mapping you are specifying the name of a controller as your resource, which doesn't make sense.  That could be a domain class, but not a controller.

If all you want to do is map a url to particular action in the controller you can do something like this in UrlMappings.groovy...

```
"/LoginController/login.json"(controller: 'login', action: 'login')
```

Normally you wouldn't have "Controller" in the url so something like this would be more common...

```
"/login/login.json"(controller: 'login', action: 'login')
```

From the little code snippet it also isn't clear what role you want JSON to play.  Maybe you just want something like this...

```
"/login"(controller: 'login', action: 'login')
```

If you can further describe what you are trying to accomplish I can clarify.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is that a Single-Page-Application authenticates against a Grails backend.  Essentially, the Flex frontend will send an HTTP Request to my LoginController containing the user/pass combo.  The controller will then return the result of that authentication attempt and set the session authentication properties.  The biggest issue is that the RESTful documentation of Grails concerns their being a domain object.  Whereas I don't have an object, I just want to hit an endpoint with parameters.  Hope this helped.

Comment: If all you want to do is hit an endpoint with parameters then you don’t need to involve the resource attribute (there is no resource to manage).

You could have a url mapping like this:

    "/login"(controller: 'login', action: 'login')

You could pass the username and password as normal request parameters or represent them in the request body as of JSON or XML or whatever.

Then in your controller action, do whatever you need to do with those parameters and render whatever response is appropriate (JSON or otherwise).

Is that helpful or do your requirements call for something more than that?

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  The first example of mapping the controller and the action worked like a charm.  Also, thanks for showing me the routes mapping code, it will be a time saver in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to getting a listing of routes (e.g. URL Mappings) you can run `grails url-mappings-report`

Also note to modify url-mapping to look like:

```
"/LoginController/login.json"(controller: "login", action: "login")
```

If `resource` is used then default action methods has to be show, create, update and delete

```
//Using resource: would look for a show() action method for a GET 
//request which you don't have in your case. And, note name of controller used 
//is login instead of LoginController
"/LoginController/login.json"(resource: "login")
```

As far as the 404 is concerned it's looking for a corresponding view called "hello.gsp" If you want to render text then use:

```
render text: 'hello'
```

Comment: Actually `resource: "login"` will not work here in this case at all. I should edit more. It would look for `show` action method for GET requests.

Comment: None of that makes sense unless you have a domain class called Login.  I think you may be confused about the role of the resource attribute.  See my other response.

Comment: Can't we have a controller as a resource in Url Mapping? I have been using that way till now. @JeffScottBrown

Comment: @JeffScottBrown With this mapping `"/sample"(resource: "sample")` I am able to hit `show()` action in `SampleController` when hitting `http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/sample`. There is no `Sample` domain class in my sample app.

Comment: @dmahapatro That doesn't really make sense.  If you create a simple example and push the project to a github repo I will show you why that doesn't make sense.

Comment: If there is no Sample domain class then what is the show() action in your SampleController doing?  Is it showing an instance of some other domain class?

Comment: `show()` can do something totally unrelated to any domain class. I am about to push the sample project to github.

Comment: Here is the [sample github project](https://github.com/dmahapatro/UrlMappingDemo) for reference. @JeffScottBrown

Comment: I know that show can do something unrelated to any domain class.  I was asking what your show action is doing to know if resource is the right thing to be using.  The original note in this thread is too vague to know what he is really trying to accomplish.

Comment: That sample project doesn't do anything at all related to resources.  You may as well just have a URL mapping which points to the show action.  Can you represent something in that app which demonstrates why you want to use the resource attribute?

Comment: OP has a login controller which would do some stuff irrespective of any underlying domain class as far now. Based on that statement, login controller can be a RESTful resource for all http methods and can map to corresponding action methods if `resource: logn` is used.  I added as a comment that he cannot use `resource` since he has `login()` action and there is no `show()` action to use. If this is not right then I am wrong in this understanding. @JeffScottBrown

Comment: It isn't clear what REST has to do with this.  For example, what does it mean to send a GET request to the show() action of a LoginController, or a PUT request to the update() action.

Comment: What I see from here is that OP is concerned with an SPA talking to this as a RESTful endpoint, but I also agree with the definition of REST that there is no Resource/Entity to work with, it is only the Login functionality. Using controller and action in mapping makes more sense than using `resource: 'login'`. @JeffScottBrown

Comment: @dmahapatro That makes no sense to me but it doesn't have to.  If it works for him then all is well.

Comment: I see that the last comment from @dmahapatro was edited after I responded to it but I am not sure how to view what the edit is.  As it is written right now, I agree with it.  When I said "That makes no sense..." the comment was either worded differently, or I misread it.

Comment: May be it was between my typo fixes, but I meant what I have mentioned above. Thanks. It was good to talk about. :) @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 1):

The original post includes this:

```
package orlandograils
class LoginController {

    static allowedMethods = [login: "POST", login: "GET"]

    def login(String username, String password )
    {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

The allowedMethods property there is bogus.  Keys in a Map have to be unique.  That code attempts to  put the key login in the Map twice.  If the intent is to say that the login method may be accessed via POST or GET then this makes sense...

```
static allowedMethods = [login: ['POST', 'GET']]
```

The code as written is valid, but it doesn't do what it was probably intended to do.  That Map will evaluate to only have 1 value associated with the login key.  That doesn't have anything to do with Grails, that is just standard Map behavior.

```
$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (2.1.9, JVM: 1.7.0_45)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> [login: 'GET', login: 'POST']
===> {login=POST}
groovy:000>
```

Notice that the expression evaluates to a Map with the value "POST" associated with the login key.